# Make chromium as default application available?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I have downloaded Chromium from https://download-chromium.appspot.com/ and I would like that it appears:

[image]

in the list web. So that I can set as default web app. I have not installed Chromium just downloaded the binaries and it is executable.

The question is, how to make Chromium available in the list of web and create symlink to Chromium executable.

Comment: If you do not install it how and why do you think it would be a selection in this list? If you want it to be the default install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Including the custom installed Chromium as an option in the "Default Applications" dialog**

The list of default applications in the "Default Applications" dialog is generated based on the information about mime types the application can handle. That information is provided through the `.desktop` launcher of the application.

Thus, [create a valid `.desktop` launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand) for your application. Include a line `MimeType=` to provide the mimetypes it can handle and include at least `x-scheme-handler/ftp;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;` for it to become included in the dialog.

**Creating a symlink to the custom installed Chromium**

This is simply a matter of creating a standard symbolic link in a directory that is included in your search path. Conventionally, a good location is `/usr/local/bin` where executables are kept that are manually installed, outside of the regular package management systems (currently the traditional APT and the newer snap systems in Ubuntu).

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/executable  /usr/local/bin/chromium-browser
```

would create a symbolic link `chromium-browser`, allowing you to run the executable `/path/to/executable` by typing "chromium-browser" in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

(With Ubuntu 20.10) I do have the choice of Chromium in Settings > Default Applications > Web.

You should install Chromium in a standard way, for example, from Ubuntu Software (search in Activities).